# Regarding PCI Express issue

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, pci-e

I am working on Freescale P2041RDB, I have designed my own customized board  similar to the RDB. But my board has few changes, like it doesn't have SPD controlled RAM and the CPLD is used only for Reset purpose and my board has a Pericom 1-to-4 PCIe switch. My problem is that when I try to access the PCI devices I am not able to do so. But when I try accessing it through U-Boot the device gets read, but the same thing when I try doing it with the Kernel, my system can't read the devices.
With the P2041RDB the PCIe works fine, I am able to access the PCI Devices.
I am using Yocto Embedded Linux kernel by Freescale.

Comment: As we cannot verify the signal integrity on your board (done some PCIe hardware myself), it is not possible to tell where the problem is. Best would be to use an appropriate scope with differential probe, but that is far beyond this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your device tree file according to your custom hardware. Devices are detected through uboot which means hardware wise it is ok but in kernel it is not able to detect which means device tree need to be modify.

Answer (score 0):

Ｉ think you should check the device tree file, to make sure the configuration of PCIe is correct according your board. since u-boot can access your device then there should not any hardware fault on it.